# WebView renders CSS different compared to browser

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying out Capacitor together with Angular. I'm not using Ionic.

When running my app in the Android emulator, the styles are off. As you can see below the gradient background goes on top of the "Increment" button, while in the browser everything looks fine.

Do I need to provide some additional CSS in order for styles to apply properly with Capacitor?

Here's the HTML and CSS for the rendered component.

```
<div class="incrementor">
    <h1>Count: {{ count }}</h1>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
</div>
<div class="gradient">
    <!-- Gradient -->
</div>
```

```
:host {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.incrementor {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.gradient {
    min-height: 1024px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a0fe65 10%, #fa016d 100%);
}
```

What could be the reason for WebView not rendering the styles exactly as Chrome does?

[image: Chrome]

[image: Android]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by upgrading Android to version 10 (API 29). The problem occurred on Android version 9.0 Pie (API 28).